# About SVM, what is the role of soft margin？

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I 've read a bit of soft margin.In real-world tasks it is often difficult to determine the appropriate kernel function that makes a training sample linearly separable in feature space; even if one happens to find a kernel function that makes the training set linearly separable in feature space, it is difficult to conclude that the seemingly linear result is not due to overfitting.One way to alleviate this problem is to allow the support vector machine to make errors on some samples. To do this, the concept of "soft margins" is introduced.But I don't really understand why it's okay to do that.I was hoping someone could illustrate it with pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`sklearn.svm.SVC`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC), in which parameter C controls the softness of margin [[1](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/281B-spring04/lectures/lec6.pdf)]. [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_margin.html) is a demonstration to illustrate the effect.

[image]

Comment: By soft margin,you can consider more data？

Comment: Yes, but that in itself is not the goal. It allows for errors in the training set (e.g., noise and outliers), in the interest of of learning a more generalizable model. Hard margin SVM works only when the training set is linearly separable without any errors.

Comment: ,emm, i think it consider more data by soft margin to allow for error in the training,not right?